# Extracting p-values from a large list of lm

Tags: r, list, group-by, lm

I am trying to extract p-values from a large list of lm which I created by:

```
S_models <- dlply(S, "BayStation", function(df) 
  lm(Temp ~ Date, data = df))
```

This leaves me with 24 lists of lm for each group (BayStation). I was able to extract the intersect and slope using:

```
coef<-ldply(S_models, coef)
```

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to get a list or dataframe of p-values from this large list without doing it individually or manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `sapply`/`lapply` :

```
result <- sapply(S_models, function(x) summary(x)$coefficients[,4])
#With `lapply`
#result <- lapply(S_models, function(x) summary(x)$coefficients[,4])
```

Comment: so doing this ended up giving me values for both date and intercept, but neither are the p-values

Comment: @Ronak  I'm running something like this to filter my model `bb <- Filter(function(x) {
  summary(x)$adj.r.squared > .83}, models)` is it possible to do the same with pvalue  `#result <- lapply(S_models, function(x) summary(x)$coefficients[,4]) 
` iI tried but i think i doing the syntax wrong

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map`

```
library(purrr)
result <- map(S_models, ~ summary(.x)$coefficients[,4])
```

Answer (score 0):

The following uses base R only and gets the p-values with the function `pf`. The quantile and the degrees of freedom are in the list returned by `summary`.

```
sapply(S_models, function(x){
  ff <- summary(x)$fstatistic
  pf(ff[1], df1 = ff[2], df2 = ff[3], lower.tail = FALSE)
})
```